# GridView background click listener

Tags: android, xml, layout, gridview

Is there a way to do click listener on background in GridView ? Here is the image which show my situation.

[image]

I have listener on elements and linear layout but how can i do click listener on background GridView (green part only) ?

Comment: Try to use gridView.setOnTouchListener(..); I don`t no why, but setOnClickListener cause an application crash.